Circular definition with struct and function in C
I have these two simplified files:
lexer.h
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

#include "expand_array.h"

// Union to store token value
typedef union {
    //Problem is here bcs of circular definition
    //----------------------------------------
    DynamicCharArray arr; // For identifiers, strings, ...

    int intValue;                       // For integer literals
    float floatValue;                   // For floating-point literals
} TokenValue;

// Structure representing a token
typedef struct {
    TokenValue value;    // Value of the token
} Token;

#endif

expand_array.h
#ifndef EXPAND_ARRAY
#define EXPAND_ARRAY

#include <stdio.h>
#include "lexer.h"

// Definition of the structure for a dynamic array
typedef struct {
    char *stringValue;  // Pointer to a dynamically allocated array of characters
    size_t size;        // Current number of characters in the array
    size_t capacity;    // Capacity of the array 
} DynamicCharArray;

void init_array(Token *token);

void free_array(Token *token);

void add_char(Token *token, int c);

#endif // EXPAND_ARRAY

The problem is, lexer.h needs expand_array.h for DynamicCharArray definition but expand_array.h needs lexer.h for Token definition.
Each definition of function in compilation gets: error: unknown type name ‘Token’
I have looked through other questions regarding forward declarations, but I haven't found a solution that resolves this specific issue.
How can I restructure this code to resolve the circular dependency while keeping the necessary relationships between these two files?

What is 'forward declaration' and the difference between 'typedef struct X' and 'struct X'?

These kind of questions come up frequently. The answer is that it never makes sense for two headers to have mutual dependencies or your program design is incorrect. Fixing the program design is the only correct solution. In proper program design, things are broken down into autonomous classes which are only concerned about their own designated task and ignore the rest of the world. And so your whole program dependency tree should look like a top-down tree with your main.c program in the very top.

Refactor to use one common header, used by both, that defines the shared data structure.

Also, just stop using typedef's.  Use them only for function pointer types.  It really does make the syntax clearer if you stop using them for structs and unions.

@UlrichEckhardt It's not that easy - they can't code themselves out of of a flawed design. They say that some array depends on a token and a token depends on an array. Once you've come up with something artificial like that, it's like determining if the chicken or the egg came first.

Instead, the correct solution is to step back and specify what the program should be doing, then consider how to break that down in modules that make sense for their designated purpose. Don't come up with artificial relations/constructs/layers that have no relevance for what the program should actually be doing. If you need to make some generic ADT/class like an array one fine - but that one has absolutely nothing to do with lexers - if written correctly it doesn't really care about what type it is storing internally.

The problem is, lexer.h needs expand_array.h for DynamicCharArray definition but expand_array.h needs lexer.h for Token definition. Why does both of those need the other?  Your DynamicCharArray has no dependencies outside of standard C objects.

@WilliamPursell "Also, just stop using typedef's" That however, is pure subjective coding style. I did make an attempt to list actual reasons for structs with/without typedef here: Are there technical reasons to pick one struct coding style over the other?

Moving DynamicCharArray into its own header file "dynchar_array.h" would break the circular dependency if "lexer.h" included "dynchar_array.h" instead of "expand_array.h".

Why does the expand_array.h header declare the functions taking a Token?  The Token type is defined in lexer.h — the functions could (IMO should) be declared in lexer.h and not expand_array.h.  Simply declaring the functions after the declaration of Token would resolve the problem.

The specific issue can be resolved by moving some definitions into a third header. The only thing in "expand_array.h" that "lexer.h" depends on is the definition of DynamicCharArray, which only depends on standard types, so moving the definition of DynamicCharArray into a third header will break the circular dependency:
dynchar_array.h
#ifndef DYNCHAR_ARRAY_H
#define DYNCHAR_ARRAY_H

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
    char *stringValue;  // Pointer to a dynamically allocated array of characters
    size_t size;        // Current number of characters in the array
    size_t capacity;    // Capacity of the array 
} DynamicCharArray;

#endif // DYNCHAR_ARRAY_H

lexer.h
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

#include "dynchar_array.h"

// Union to store token value
typedef union {
    DynamicCharArray arr; // For identifiers, strings, ...
    int intValue;         // For integer literals
    float floatValue;     // For floating-point literals
} TokenValue;

// Structure representing a token
typedef struct {
    TokenValue value;    // Value of the token
} Token;

#endif // LEXER_H

expand_array.h
#ifndef EXPAND_ARRAY_H
#define EXPAND_ARRAY_H

#include "lexer.h"

void init_array(Token *token);
void free_array(Token *token);
void add_char(Token *token, int c);

#endif // EXPAND_ARRAY_H


Changing your code as little as possible (other than removing the gratuitous typedefs for clarity), you can avoid the circular dependency with:
lexer.h:
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H
#include "expand_array.h"

union TokenValue {
    struct DynamicCharArray arr;
    int intValue;
    float floatValue;
};

struct Token {
    union TokenValue value;
};
#endif

expand_array.h:
#ifndef EXPAND_ARRAY
#define EXPAND_ARRAY
struct Token;              // forward declaration of struct Token
struct DynamicCharArray {
    char *stringValue;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};

void init_array(struct Token *token);
void free_array(struct Token *token);
void add_char(struct Token *token, int c);
#endif // EXPAND_ARRAY

